# Can't assign value to out of scope variable inside image.onload()

Tags: jquery, image, scope, onload

This is what I have:

```
var test = '';
var img = new Image();
img.src = 'https://blahblah';
img.onload = function () {
    test = 'Sam';
}
```

When I `console.log(test)`, it shows nothing. How can I assign value to `test` inside `onload`?

Comment: Have you appended `img` to the DOM?  You'll need to do that before `onload` will fire.

Comment: @SimianAngel, yes, I did, and it is there.

Comment: Hmm...once I append `img` to the DOM, I have it showing up in this CodePen:  http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pyXQbv?editors=1111

Comment: The value is still different outside of scope. When I `console.log(test)` after adding to DOM, the value is still `''`

Comment: @SimianAngel - I think the asker wants to modify a variable outside of the function's scope within the function, your codepen does not reflect this.

Comment: @SeattleAls - Your goal is to modify the test variable but that variable won't exist inside the function's scope. A cheap(and dirty) fix would be making test a global variable.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2762516/changing-a-variable-out-of-scope) question might help you. This one has a good bit on what [scopes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript?rq=1) are.

Comment: @AustinSchmidt - It's not about the scope. It's about time. See my updated JsFiddle. The value gets set correctly, but only after onload is invoked : jsfiddle.net/y7Lnp6q1/2

Comment: @MaheshChavda Good point, the image load will be asynchronous which could easily be an issue depending on how OP lays out their code. I'd also like to point out that you made test a global in your example. Really though, OP needs to post more relevant code so that the issue can be made more clear.

Answer (score 0):

See this jsFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/y7Lnp6q1/1/

It depends on where you do console.log. See my comments in following code:

```
var test = "";
var img = new Image();
img.src = 'https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/images/recipes01.png';
img.onload = function () {
    test = "Sam";
    console.log("test = " + test); // Will output "test = Sam"
}
console.log("test = " + test); // Will output "test = ", because onload is not yet triggered by this time.
```

Comment: I know. That is the problem. I need it to be `'Sam'` outside `img.onload`

Comment: @SeattleAls It will be, once `onload` runs.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan It won't, the scope of the variable test(declared outside the function) doesn't extend into the function. The OP needs to likely rethink their design.

Comment: It's not about the scope. It's about time. See my updated JsFiddle. The value gets set correctly, but only after onload is invoked : https://jsfiddle.net/y7Lnp6q1/2/